# createDataFrame not working in Spark 2.0.0

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work through some of the examples in the new Spark 2.0 documentation. I am working in Jupyter Notebooks and command line. I can create a `SparkSession` with no problem. However when I try to create a `dataframe` I get the error of:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'createDataFrame'

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Search").config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate

d = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}]
spark.createDataFrame(d).collect()
```

Can someone please explain what I need to do to fix this error ? I have searched through the official documentation and not found anything on this particular error. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getOrCreate` is a method on `SparkSession.Builder`. You need to invoke it by adding the parentheses after:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Search").config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
```

See for more information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html

In general, the `'function' object has no attribute` error is very common when you are accidentally referencing a function rather than invoking it.